# After input search field, fetch new results (nuxt, vuex)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

I am having troubles on how to return new search results after a user did a new search in my Nuxt Application. The search query needs to return users based on postcode and I stored everything so far in store. This is my code:

/store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  filter: {
    search: '',
  },
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_TUTORS(state, tutors) {
    state.tutors = tutors
  },
}

export const actions = {
  loadAllTutors({ commit }) {
    const postcode = '1111' // this needs to be variable 

    this.$axios
      .post('http://api.com/end/point', {
        postcode,
      })

      .then(({ data }) => {
        commit(
          'SET_TUTORS',
          data.map((item) => item.attributes)
        )
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  },
}
```

page.vue

```
<template>
<input
            id="search_field"
            class="block w-full h-full py-4 pl-10 pr-3 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:placeholder-gray-400 sm:text-sm"
            placeholder="Vul jouw postcode in"
            type="search"
          />
 <ul class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6">
            <li
              v-for="tutor in tutors"
              :key="tutor.name"
              class="overflow-hidden bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-md"
            >
              <div class="flex">
              </div>
            </li>
</ul>
</template>

export default {
  name: 'Zoeken',
  components: {},

  async fetch({ store }) {
    await store.dispatch('loadAllTutors')
  },

  data: () => ({
    postcode: '1111',
    attributes: [],
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated', 'loggedInUser']),
    ...mapState(['tutors']),
  },
  methods: {},
  layout: 'app',
  middleware: 'auth',
}
```

What do I need to change so the index.js in the store will get the search input and refresh the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the postcode through the second argument of your `loadAllTutors` action ([Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)).

`store/index.js`

```js
loadAllTutors({ commit }, postcode) {
  // ...
}
```

Then you should create a new method on your page component that you can call to dispatch your store action.

`pages/page.vue`

```js
methods: {
  async fetchTutors() {
    const postcode = '1111';
    await store.dispatch('loadAllTutors', postcode);
  }
}
```

Now if you want to trigger your new method through an event like `@input` on your input element, you can use the event object directly to read the postcode ([Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#method-event-handlers) - `const postcode = event.target.value`)

If you trigger it through another element (like another button) you could use v-model ([Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)) to access your postcode through the data object.

`pages/page.vue`

```js
// Use with @input="fetchTutors" on textbox (or any other event)
// Must be invoked through the search input element
async fetchTutors(event) {
  await store.dispatch('loadAllTutors', event.target.value);
}

// Use with v-model="postcode" on textbox
// Can be invoked from any element
async fetchTutors() {
  await store.dispatch('loadAllTutors', this.postcode);
}
```

I hope this solves your issue. How exactly you trigger the method or retrieve your postcode is for you to decide. This is just a basic example.

Comment: Many thanks! I moved the async function inside the methods and changed it like this:

```
methods: {
    async fetchTutors() {
      const postcode = this.postcode
      await this.$store.dispatch('loadAllTutors', postcode)
    },
  },
```

Now it is working almost perfectly. The results are not refreshed on the display, only when changing routes back and forth. But this is some other problem i need to debug. Thanks

Comment: @DennisKraaijeveld I don't know how you trigger that method. Do you use a button?
(And it would be very nice of you to accept my answer if it helped you out)